# структура для хранения цвета С++

Tags: c++, массивы, структуры

> Разработать структуру для хранения цвета (компоненты `Red`, `Green`, `Blue`).
>
> Предусмотреть возможность формирования цвета из отдельных компонентов, получение любой компоненты, увеличение/уменьшение яркости всех компонент, увеличение/уменьшение яркости отдельной компоненты.
>
> Разработайте структуру для хранения данных о цветном кружке + функции для манипулирования переменными такого типа.
>
> Создайте массив цветных кружков и разработайте функцию сортировки кружков по разным признакам: по площади, по цвету, по удалению от начала координат.

Направьте в нужном направлении, что нужно сделать.

Думаю для структуры цвета так:

`struct Cvet{ red = , green=, blue= }`

или как-то по-другому надо?

Answer (score 2):

На словах? Да, структура или класс (раз хотят функциональность получения компонент - значит, класс с инкапсулированными данными...) типа

```
class Color {
  public:
    Color() = default;
    Color(int r, int g, int b):r(r),g(g),b(b){}
    ~Color() = default;

  void setRed(int R) { r = R; };
  void setGreen(int G) ...;
  void setBlue(int B) ...;

  int getRed() const { return r; };
  int getGreen() const ...;
  int getBlue() const ...;

  void brightness(int value, int color = 0); // Для всех цветов или для конкретного

  private:
    int r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
};
```

Дальше просто расписываете функции. С яркостью нужно повозиться, чтобы решить, как она должна работать - задавать абсолютные значения или относительное увеличение, например. Возможно, добавить поле максимального значения цвета - типа `static const int maxValue = ...;`

Ну, а с кружками - точно так же:

```
class Circle {
...
  private:
    Color color;
    int x, y;
};
```

ну и подумайте, какие функции нужны...

Comment: А в чем смысл писать класс с приватными полями, а потом делать тривиальный сеттер и геттер. Не лучше сразу структуру писать? Тем более что данные "плоские"?

Comment: @pavel Я же написал - "*раз хотят функциональность получения компонент - значит, класс с инкапсулированными данными*". Смысла почти никакого, но в учебных заданиях дидактический смысл часто важнее здравого.

Comment: @pavel, смысл в инкапсуляции. Если вдруг разработчику стукнет в голову хранить цвет в виде строки `#RRGGBB`, или одного целого числа, или HSV, или CMYK, то тогда будет меняться только реализация сеттеров/геттеров, а не тонны кода, который использует открытые переменные `r`, `g` и `b`

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb спорно... имхо лучше поменять _всё_ чем пытаться 4 переменные загнать в 3 или ещё хуже - не заметить что цветовая схема другая и вычислить что-то не то. Лучше уже 2 структуры и преобразователь тогда.

Comment: @pavel, так а кто говорит что схема другая? Схема RGB. сеттеры/геттеры оперируют красной, зеленой и синей составляющей. А что там внутри никто знать не должен. Сегодня у меня три инта, завтра массив интов, после завтра масив чаров. Все эти преобразования не должны затрагивать другой код

Comment: классы конечно может и хорошо, но в задании структуры, и этого требует сам преподаватель

Comment: Ну напишите вместо `class` - `struct`, только и всего. Только иметь в структуре функциональность для установки и получения значений полей - тихий бред. Вы уверены, что слово "структура" подразумевает именно `struct`, а не гораздо более общее понятие структуры данных?

Comment: да, именно struct, классы будут уже потом, в следующем семестре

Comment: А вы знаете чем отличаются классы и структуры? Во-первых, в структурах по умолчанию область видимости `public`, а в классах `private`. Во-вторых, структуры по умолчанию наследуются как `public`, а классы как `private`. Вот и все